# PHP variable loses value

Tags: php, mysql

Have a report showing query output for invoicing clients at a feedyard. Some queries would produce a blank page, instead of the R1 or R3 layout that came as a variable from the query.

Finally figured out that the if statement to choose the report layout was not receiving the value. All questions here and other forums involved passing the variable across pages or methods when it lost the value, this is the next line.

Echoed the variable right before the if statement and it shows R1, but in the next line the variable is not equal to R1. (I am moving to PDO connection, but client waited until harvest in full swing to ask for formula/input changes and new reports, closed system on their network.)

$theq is query with the correct syntax, it generates the right answer, so I'm starting the code block at where the $report variable is set, showing the code until $report isn't the same value...

```
if ($getticketsfetch['highmoisture'] === "R2") {
    $report = "R1";
} else {
    $report = $getticketsfetch['highmoisture'];
}

if (mysql_numrows($gettickets) < 1) {
    echo 'No tickets to report on with those parameters, please go back and `try again ';
    echo '<input type=button value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1)">';
} else {
//run report
    /* echo $theq; for debugging, this query pasted in phpMyAdmin executes properly
      echo $report; for debugging shows R1 */
    if ($report === "R1") {
        //USE R1 LAYOUT
    } else {
        //USE R3 LAYOUT
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Please, I need some input - it still is not working. 
I've changed the code multiple times using:

```
`echo $report //see which report layout
 if($report === "R1") {
         //USE R1 LAYOUT
    } else {
        //USE R3 LAYOUT
      }
    }
```

The echo shows R1, the layout uses R3

Change code to read:

```
    echo $report //see which report layout
 if($report == "R1") {
         //USE R1 LAYOUT
    } else {
        //USE R3 LAYOUT
      }
    }
```

Still uses R3 layout everytime, even when $report = R1
Changed to read:

```
    echo $report //see which report layout
 if($report !=="R3") {
         //USE R1 LAYOUT
    } else {
        //USE R3 LAYOUT
      }
    }
```

The !== was working, now client finds it always goes to R3 layout again.
Production server Hostcentric MySQL - 5.5.44-0; PHP 5.3

Comment: I don't see any query, and it's not clear what variable you are talking about. What is the actual problem?

Comment: I didn't waste the space showing the query because it runs properly and feeds R1 or R3 to the code properly. The start of the code block in the question is where the $report variable gets its value.  The actual problem is $report is correct, $report is R1 on the echo line shown in code and the next line with the if($report === "R1") it does not equal R1 and goes to the other layout. I've tried it with == and ===.

Comment: Does your `$report` value have any whitespace that, perhaps, you aren't noticing when it's echoed? If it has a space or a tab hanging out before or after the `R1` or `R3` value then your if/else is going to always head to the `else`... Perhaps trim that variable before testing it. Perhaps sometimes it has some whitespace and others not depending on the query, which is why you are getting intermittent failures/successes.

Comment: I added the var_dump($report, bin2hex($report), bin2hex('R1')); and the response follows: string 'R1' (length=2)    string '5231' (length=4)  
string '5231' (length=4).  I went ahead and put if (trim($Report) != "R3") to catch any inconsistencies, though it is hard coded when data is entered with the weight tickets whether or not it is R1 or R3.  Thank you both. We'll get some more tested, first few acted properly.